# How to attribute str_replace in CSS?

Tags: php, css, str-replace

Is there anyway to use `str_replace` in css?

Here is my issue:

I am working with PHP and Wordpress on my own them. I have a `do_action` function in a template page that activates the [Posts Per Cat](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/posts-per-cat/) plugin, which lists my posts in certain categories on a page. It shows up only the posts titles, but I would like to make break line and italic in my titles.

When the `do_action` function calls my post's title, I would like it to format the titles as I had set it up in my `str_replace` function that you can see below. But now, the plugin (`do_action` function) and the `str_replace` doesn't work together like this. I was thinking to achieve that in CSS, but if you know how to do it in PHP I am on.

**Here is an example of a title:**

ALLEINANSPRUCH Arne Schmitt, Nico Joana Weber 4 Februar – 30 April 2017

**And the expected result:**

ALLEINANSPRUCH

Arne Schmitt, Nico Joana Weber

*4 Februar – 30 April 2017*

**Here is my HTML (loaded by the plugin)**

```html
<div id="ppc-box">

  <div class="ppc-box one">
    <div class="ppc">
      <h3>CURRENTLY</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/nouvelle-exposition-2/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article BOOK LAUNCH &amp; KÜNSTLERGESPRÄCH published at 18 juillet 2017 10 h 57 min">BOOK LAUNCH &amp; KÜNSTLERGESPRÄCH</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/alleinanspruch/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article PARKFIELD STUDIES | Marianna Christofides | &lt;i&gt;27 August – 30 August 2017&lt;/i&gt; published at 18 juillet 2017 10 h 59 min">PARKFIELD STUDIES | Marianna Christofides | &lt;i&gt;27 August – 30 August 2017&lt;/i&gt;</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/fourth-post-test/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article ALLEINANSPRUCH | Arne Schmitt, Nico Joana Weber | &lt;i&gt;4 Februar – 30 April 2017&lt;/i&gt; published at 20 juillet 2017 17 h 52 min">ALLEINANSPRUCH | Arne Schmitt, Nico Joana Weber | &lt;i&gt;4 Februar – 30 April 2017&lt;/i&gt;</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="ppc-box one">
    <div class="ppc">
      <h3>PREVIEW</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/second-post-test/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article RESPAWN | Eloïse Bonneviot, Anne de Boer | &lt;i&gt;4 July – 30 July 2017&lt;/i&gt; published at 20 juillet 2017 17 h 50 min">RESPAWN | Eloïse Bonneviot, Anne de Boer | &lt;i&gt;4 July – 30 July 2017&lt;/i&gt;</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/third-post-test/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article THE COMMON TOAD | Victoria Adam | &lt;i&gt;27 Mai – 30 Juli 2017&lt;/i&gt; published at 20 juillet 2017 17 h 51 min">THE COMMON TOAD | Victoria Adam | &lt;i&gt;27 Mai – 30 Juli 2017&lt;/i&gt;</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**Here is the `do_action` function that activates the plugin in my template php page**

```html
<?php (do_action('ppc'));?>
```

**Here is the `str_replace` I used previously (without the plugin). Now that the plugin is loaded, the `srt_replace` doesn't work anymore.**

```html
<?php $first = str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title()); 
      echo str_replace('REPLACE_ME', '<i>REPLACE_ME</i>', $first);?>
```

The `get_the_title` of that last code is not needed anymore, because the plugin already load the titles. How can I `str_replace` in that `do_action` plugin function?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to achieve with this part `echo str_replace('REPLACE_ME', '<i>REPLACE_ME</i>', $first);` ? It seems this part `$first = str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title());` would do the job.

Comment: This is a previous code I was using to replace " | " by line break and <i> by italic attribute, directly in my Wordpress title. It works. But now that I am loading a plugin, with the do_action function, I don't know how to combine them together.

Comment: and with only this `$first = str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title());  echo $first;` what happens?